# Loading too much into the program? (Java)

Tags: java, serialization, ram

I have programmed a cookbook in Java. For that I created a Recipe-Object where informations like the name and a picture of the dish is saved.

I put all this objects into a List and serialized the List with all the recipes. When the cookbook is opened again, all these recipes (each recipe has a picture) are loaded in the program again.

If there are 500+ recipes, then 500+ pictures must be loaded into the program.

**My question:**

- Will these pictures be saved into the RAM of my computer?
- Would it be better to serialize each recipe into an own file and only
  load the recipe which is selected?

Comment: While converting object to serialize form generally you specify the saved location. And when required you read again from the saved location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *serialization*; at least on a conceptual level.

The point is: when some custom object O of yours consumes X bytes of data; then those X bytes of data are allocated within the JVM as long as that object O is "alive" within your JVM.

In other words: when you directly put image bytes into your objects; then it doesn't matter if those objects are created via *new* or if they are read from some byte stream, or if they are read from *n* different sources.

Exactly for that reason, one would try to not "include" image bytes directly into the "business" object. For example by keeping the images as files on the hard drive; and only adding a file name to the object. Meaning: only when you actually put up a "recipe" on the screen you load the picture from the drive; in order to display it to the user.

So the answer to your question is: the **memory consumption** of your program does not care if you load serialized objects from one file, or from **n** files.

Your memory consumption much more depends on the exact inner details how you deal with "resources" that are somehow associated to your "recipe objects".

Finally: what to do really depends on your requirements. If we are talking about a small java program that is supposed on some "average desktop" machine; then keeping 500 or 1000 "live" objects in your JVM might be OK; even when each one consumes say 500 KB for pictures (but note that we already reach 250 MB of RAM consumption easily here!).

But if we are talking about some app running on a mobile phone; the for sure you **do not** want to waste 250 MB of memory and keep 500 objects there.

So, in most cases, the reasonable approach would more look like:

1. Keeping a list of **known** recipes in memory all the time
2. "Loading" recipes only when they are about to be "used"
3. Separating the recipe from "resources" (such as images) that belong to it

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try that.